# How to decompose matrix transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, transformation, linear-transformations, rigid-transformation

Let us assume $A$,$B$ and $C$ are known affine transformation matrices in homogeneous 2D space.

If it should happen that $C=A^m B^n$ for some unknown $m,n$, is there a way to detect this short of trying all the combinations? If one of $A,B$ is an identity matrix this can be determined by examining the eigenvectors, but is there an equivalent way of doing this for a product such as this?

The use-case is that I am examining a grid-like structure generated by composing transformations as described above, and I want to know if an arbitrary transformation I get can in fact be expressed as a product of exponentiated "primitive" transformations that I already know.

Comment: What are we given, and what are we trying to find?  Are we given $C$, $m$, and $n$?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom edited to specify.

Comment: Are you investigating sort of _Multigrid Methods_ ? Like in:
[DoubleGrid Calculus](http://www.alternatievewiskunde.nl/sunall/calculus.pdf) ,
[TripleGrid Calculus](http://www.alternatievewiskunde.nl/sunall/drievoud.pdf) .

Comment: @HandeBruijn Probably not; the grid I speak of exists in the linear space and can be visualized by repeatedly transforming a single point by the $A^m B^n$ combination.

Comment: Aren't $A$ and $B$ simply translations then?

Comment: @HandeBruijn Not necessarily. Either of them can be a scale matrix (for an exponential grid), one of them could be a rotation matrix (for a circular grid), or both (for spirals or such).

Comment: Are you working only on the plane? Can you represent these $A,B$ using complex functions?

Comment: @Daniel It's all on a plane. The matrices could certainly be represented using functions, but that's defeating the purpose of using matrices for transformations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A$ and $B$ commute, you can use the matrix logarithm! Sure, it's not unique but solutions only vary by integer multiples of $2\pi i$ you can check by hand whether $\log C$ looks like
$$
\log(C) = q2\pi i I + n\log(A) + m\log(A)
$$

for integers $q,n,m$. Each entry in $\log(C)$ corresponds to a linear equation $q,n,m$ must solve. It's complex,  but that doesn't matter. It's now a linear system.

Here's why commuting matters. In the real setting, $\log(ab) = \log(a)+\log(b)$ is always true. However, in the matrix setting addition does commute but multiplication may not. It turns out that 
$$
\log(AB) = \log(A)+\log(B) \quad\text{mod}\;2\pi i I
$$
is only guaranteed for $A$ and $B$ which commute. So while you can do the computation described above for $A$ and $B$ which don't commute, it'll just give you garbage. The equation $C=A^nB^m$ need not have any relation with $\log(C) = q2\pi i I + n\log(A) + m\log(A)$.

Computing logarithms is not too hard numerically. Just use the Taylor series. Computing them by hand is not too bad if $A$ or $B$ is diagonalizable.

If you go the numeric route, just be sure to check that the candidate $n$ and $m$ actually work. The matrix log can be a little sensitive near the edges of it's interval of convergence.

I know that this $A$ and $B$ commuting is a fairly special case, but you gotta start somewhere. I'll keep thinking of what to do in the more general case.

Comment: The commutativity condition is fairly restrictive, but it does hold at least in the most common cases (translation-translation, translation/scale-translation and even if there's one rotation in the mix). What happens if they are *not* commutative and I try this?

Comment: Edited to address your question.